# ionic two tabs full width

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a view in Ionic with TABS that I want to make their content 50%+50% of the width of the screen, the current result is as follows (theres some margin on the sides):
http://play.ionic.io/app/e59562e15d95

In the view with three tabs, you can see that the tabs are indeed full width.:
http://play.ionic.io/app/637826dbec6c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this :http://play.ionic.io/app/35f4dc56d51e 
Make a class

```
.full-width-tab{
  max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Add it to tabs item

```
<a class="tab-item active full-width-tab" href="#">
    One
  </a>
    <a class="tab-item full-width-tab" href="#">
    Two
  </a>
```